# iPhone - 3 multiple detections of UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios

I have 3 UIGestureRecognizers attached to a view: one finger double tap, two fingers double tap and one finger triple tap. The problem is this: when I triple tap, it fires the method that should be fired by double tap then the method for triple tap.

This is how I added it.

```
// one finger double tap
doubleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
              initWithTarget:self 
              action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)] autorelease];
[doubleTap setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];
[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[doubleTapDoisDedos setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[doubleTap setDelegate:self];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];  


// two fingers double tap
twoFingerDoubleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
              initWithTarget:self 
              action:@selector(handleDoubleTapTwoFingers:)] autorelease];
[twoFingerDoubleTap setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];
[twoFingerDoubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[twoFingerDoubleTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];
[twoFingerDoubleTap setDelegate:self]; 
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerDoubleTap]; 



// triple tap com um dedo faz as cartas se empilharem
tripleTapOneFinger = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
              initWithTarget:self 
              action:@selector(handleTripleTap:)] autorelease];
[tripleTapOneFinger setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];
[tripleTapOneFinger setNumberOfTapsRequired:3];
[tripleTapOneFinger setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[tripleTapOneFinger setDelegate:self]; 
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:tripleTapOneFinger];
```

and yes, I have tried to add these, without success

```
[doubleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapTwoFingers];   
[doubleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tripleTapOneFinger];  

[doubleTapTwoFingers requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];   
[doubleTapTwoFingers requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tripleTapOneFinger];  

[tripleTapOneFinger requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];   
[tripleTapOneFinger requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapTwoFingers];
```

what am I missing?

is there a way to, inside the handle method, detect the number of taps?

thanks

Comment: You should really only need `[doubleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tripleTapOneFinger];`; There are no other conflicts. I've noticed before too many dependancies confuses the recognizer.

Comment: YESSSSSS. Thanks. Please add this as answer, so I can give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding too many gesture recognizer dependancies through `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` will cause problems. Just add the one dependency that is needed, in your case:

```
[doubleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tripleTapOneFinger];
```