# LongPressGesture And TapGesture At Same Time

Tags: ios, tap, long-press

So for the app I'm working on I am handling a UILongPressGesture. While that is being done I need to also be able to tap the phone and handle the UITapGesture. I implemented this but it didn't work. If the UILongPressGesture isn't in progress it will call the UITapGesture but not at the same time. So how would I call them at the same time?

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    m_tapRecognize = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    m_tapRecognize.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    m_pressRecognize = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePress:)];
    m_pressRecognize.minimumPressDuration = 1.1f;
    m_pressRecognize.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    [view addGestureRecognizer:m_pressRecognize];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:m_tapRecognize];
    [view setMultipleTouchEnabled:true];
}

-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture {
    NSLog(@"Tap");
}

-(void)handlePress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)pressGesture {
    if (pressGesture.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        NSLog(@"Long Press");
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866623/ios-multiple-tap-gesture-recognizers?rq=1

Comment: Do you really mean at the same time (multiple fingers on screen)?

Comment: Yes, one should be holding down for the LongPress and another should then press for the Tap.